# Impala JDBC Driver Connection Error

Tags: java, node.js, jdbc, cloudera, impala

I'm using Node JDBC module to connect to Impala, but I'm getting a 500151 error on connection. My connection string is `jdbc:impala://myhost:21050;AuthMech=3;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;UID=user;PWD=password`

Here is the error messege:

```
Error: Error running static method
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500151) Error setting/closing session: {0}.
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.openSession(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.impala.core.ImpalaJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Caused by: com.cloudera.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500151) Error     setting/closing session: {0}.
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:156)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2ClientWrapper.recv_OpenSession(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:143)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2ClientWrapper.OpenSession(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.openSession(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.impala.core.ImpalaJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I know for sure there's nothing wrong with the credential and AuthMech. Someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I upgraded my Impala JDBC driver to 41, and got rid of `transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice` in my connection string.